# Use Excel VBA Command to delete all shapes excluding specific ShapeTypes

Tags: excel, vba

I have part drawings that I mark up with welds. Each drawing is the same but has unique serial numbers. Each weld is represented by a Circle Shape (msoShapeOval). After I hit my save function, I want all Circle Shapes (and ONLY circle shapes) removed from the drawing so that I can begin the next serial number.

I tried If statements with Shape.Type commands to delete all msoShapeOval, but the file doesn't recognize the shapes.

I also tried the opposite where If Not (textbox, OLE, picture, etc) delete shape, however that deleted ALL shapes.

```
Sub DeleteAllWelds()
Dim shp As Shape
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each shp In ws.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoShapeOval Then shp.Delete
Next shp

End Sub
```

This is the CommandButton which calls the DeleteWelds sub

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'Save and create new Weld Map for same Part Number
'Remove all weld shapes 'Reset any counters 'Reset fields in UserForm1 but not all

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Call SaveDoc
    If UserForm3_Exit.Tag = "Go" Then
        ws.Range("I2, I3, A6:K80").Value = ""
        Call DeleteAllWelds
        Unload Me
    ElseIf UserForm3_Exit.Tag = "Cancel" Then
        Unload Me
    End If
```

End Sub

Finally the Sub which creates the Oval shapes to begin with.

```
Sub ShapeWithNum()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 20, 40, 20, 20).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = _
        msoAlignCenter
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = buttonCell
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 1). _
        ParagraphFormat
        .FirstLineIndent = 0
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 1).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
End Sub
```

The method where I only delete msoShapeOval doesn't delete any objects, but when I use If not (mso(insert ones I need)) all objects are deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `shp.AutoShapeType` instead of `shp.Type` as commented by @AhmedAU in the comments (The comment is now deleted).

There are different kinds of shapes in Excel. For example `3D model`, `AutoShape`, `Callout` etc. You can get the entire list in [MsoShapeType enumeration (Office)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype)

So when you say `Shape.Type`, then it refers to `MsoShapeType`. Let's take an example. Insert these shapes in the worksheet

[image]

Now run this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Shp As Shape

    Set ws = Sheet1

    For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
        Debug.Print "(" & Shp.Name & ")"; "---"; Shp.Type
    Next Shp
End Sub
```

You will get this output

```
(Oval 1)--- 1
(TextBox 2)--- 17
(Straight Connector 4)--- 9
(Right Arrow 5)--- 1
(Explosion 1 6)--- 1
```

So you will notice that `Oval 1`, `Right Arrow 5` and `Explosion 1 6` have a shape type of `1`. This means (*if you refer to the above link*) these are **AutoShapes**

When you *Print* the value of `msoShapeOval` in the *Immediate Window* using `?msoShapeOval`, you will notice that the value is `9`. It definitely is not `1` So what is this value? This is the `Shape.AutoShapeType` property which has a value of `9` for `msoShapeOval`

Read up on [Shape.AutoShapeType property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.autoshapetype). It says *Returns or sets the shape type for the specified Shape or ShapeRange object, which must represent an AutoShape other than a line, freeform drawing, or connector.*

So one should know when to use the `Shp.Type` and when to use the `Shp.AutoShapeType`

Now try this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Shp As Shape

    Set ws = Sheet1

    For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
        Debug.Print "(" & Shp.Name & ")"; "--- Shape Type: "; Shp.Type; "--- AutoShape Type: "; Shp.AutoShapeType
    Next Shp
End Sub
```

You will see the output as

```
(Oval 1)--- Shape Type:  1 --- AutoShape Type:  9
(TextBox 2)--- Shape Type:  17 --- AutoShape Type:  1
(Straight Connector 4)--- Shape Type:  9 --- AutoShape Type: -2
(Right Arrow 5)--- Shape Type:  1 --- AutoShape Type:  33
(Explosion 1 6)--- Shape Type:  1 --- AutoShape Type:  89
```

So in your code, simply change

```
If shp.Type = msoShapeOval
```

to

```
If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval
```

Comment: Thanks and really appreciate. That’s the kind of answer I am eagerly waiting for. Think about the amount of quality information provided to SO community (beyond my scope even in dream). You made my day.

Comment: Excellent explanation Sid! I implemented your change and it runs exactly as I need it to.